# Output of find command in shell script

Tags: shell

I need to execute the following command in shell; will it give a sorted list or not?

```
find -type f -exec ls -t {} \;
```

Comment: Why didn't you test this?  This site and other forums on the internet for that matter are there to help people who at least show that they have tried to solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good guide to any public forum when posting questions.  Another more elaborate document I recommend is http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written like that, the `ls` command is run with one file at a time in whatever order `find` happens to come across the names, so there won't be any meaningful time ordering.

If you have a version of `find` that supports the POSIX 2008 `+` notation, then you can use:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -t {} +
```

and this will have `ls` list each group of files in time order, but if the command is run more than once (lots of files), then each batch will be ordered, but the groups may well be such that file 453 was created after file 2912 in the order presented.

If you need them sorted regardless of the number of files, then you probably need to use `stat` command to print the file name and modification time as a number, and then sort numerically, and finally strip the number off.

On Mac OS X, you might use:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -f '%Dm %N' {} + | sort -n | awk '{print $2}'
```

(The `%Dm` prints the modification time as a decimal number; the `%N` prints the file name.)

However, if you're on Linux, you'll need to check the manual page for Linux `stat` since it is different.  If you're on other systems, the `stat` command may or may not be available; it is not standardized by POSIX.